# Why is $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Why is $\sqrt{x^2 } = |x|$ ?

Squaring always produces a positive result, and you obviously square the equation before taking the root of it. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: What problem are you talking about? Would you mind being more specific?

Comment: @rubik Why isn't $(\sqrt{-3^2 }) = -3$ ?

Comment: @user262493 it is a mere convention: the symbol $\sqrt{}$ denotes the unique *non-negative* number such that etc.

Comment: @user262493: It is.

Comment: @user262493 Presumably, you meant $\sqrt{(-3)^2}$. Remember that $-3^2$ means $-(3^2)=-9$, but $(-3)^2$ means $(-3)\cdot(-3)=9$.

Answer (score 11):

Think about it in cases:

If $x\geq 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.

If $x<0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}$ is positive; it is actually $-x$ (which is positive because $x<0)$.

So, we find that
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2}&=\begin{cases}x & \text{if }x\geq0\\-x & \text{if }x<0\end{cases}\\&=\lvert x\rvert.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

The square root $\sqrt{x}$ for a nonnegative real number $x$ is defined as the nonnegative root of $x$. This causes the following problem:
$$\sqrt{(-3)^2} = \sqrt{9} = 3.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is true because bothe sides , squared, are equal, and because they're both non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already correctly address why the identity holds: because of the *definition* of square root. That's fine, and I won't overlap on their answers here. But you may ask, why is the square root function so defined? To this additional question, I will provide an explanation.

The square root is *defined* to be nonnegative because otherwise it wouldn't be a function. Note that the function $x \mapsto x^2$ strictly can't be inverted because every non-zero value in the range has two values mapping to it in the domain. E.g. $(-1)^2 = 1^2 = 1$. But the idea of a *square root* is so *useful*, that we do a bit of extra work and define the square root function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ such that $\sqrt{x}$ is the unique nonnegative real number such that $\sqrt{x}^2 = x$. It agrees with common sense that, by convention, the meaning of $\sqrt{x}$ is the *nonnegative* square root of $x$. To express the negative counterpart we just need to write $-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You meant $\color{red}{(}-1\color{red}{)}^2 = 1^2 = 1$.  Observe that $-1^2 = -1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = -1 \cdot 1 = -1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig well spotted, that's fixed now.