# Why does $ \sqrt{x^2} = |x| $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This equality keeps coming up in my algebra course and I don't understand why this is true. $$ \sqrt{x^2} = |x| $$ shouldn't it just be $$ \sqrt{x^2} = x $$?

Comment: your $\sqrt{x^2}=x $ is only true if $x$ is positive or zero, and $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ is $x$ is negative.

Comment: We have now four answers in the span of $2$ minutes....Do I hear $5$?  Anyone who is skilled at saying what everyone else is saying, please bid ....I hear $5$!...  Let's see how many more answerers we can get who are  all say pretty much the same thing....Monkey see, monkey do!  OOH, OOH, 3 more monkeys!

Comment: @amWhy you make me want to do it!

Comment: This must be a duplicate

Comment: 8 ... and counting.

Comment: This is almost entertaining....9 answers it is!  (Question closed!)  I'm willing for each answer to be awarded 1 pt, since the answers in total, aren't worth one upvote (maybe $9$ points in total, to be shared among 9 answerers.  That's why I think $1$ rep point each is more than generous.

Comment: (1) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716497/why-does-sqrtx2-x?rq=1; (2) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607568/is-sqrtx2-x-or-x-isnt-x2-frac12-x; (3) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419841/why-is-sqrtx2-x?rq=1; or (4) the answer cited above for which is also a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that every (positive) number has *two* numbers which square to it: e.g., $$4=2^2=(-2)^2.$$ In order to be a function, the square root operator has to *pick one* (a function can't be multivalued).

We make the convention that $\sqrt{a}$ is always the *nonnegative* square root of $a$, so e.g. $\sqrt{4}=2$ and not $-2$. But this means that we need **not** have $\sqrt{x^2}=x$! Namely, $$\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\sqrt{4}=2\not=-2.$$ Instead, what is true is that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is the "nonnegative version" of $x$ - that is, $\vert x\vert$.

Comment: I'm curious - why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote and I cannot speak for anyone else who may have (I haven't bothered to check your "ups vs. downs".  But the answer is hardly noteworthy, at best "meh".  There are answers as good or better than yours, already posted to this question that is really at least a quadruplicate question, a couple listed to the right as "related".  Too bad we can't vote to close answers as duplicate answers.

Comment: So I'm surprised that you're even "curious" about one or more downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic principle of a function: for every input, you get **only one** output.

Consider $(-9)^2$. This is $81$. If $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, then $\sqrt{81} = \sqrt{(-9)^2} = -9.$

Consider $(9)^2$. This is also $81$. If $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, then $\sqrt{81} = \sqrt{9^2} = 9$.

When I write $\sqrt{81}$, it should unambiguously give me one number, since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a function. But I have, from above, that $\sqrt{81} = 9$ and $\sqrt{81} = -9$. This doesn't work if $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a function.

Thus, we choose $\sqrt{x^2}$ to be the *positive* (technically, nonnegative) value $|x|$, by convention, so $\sqrt{81} = \sqrt{9^2}$ which also is $\sqrt{(-9)^2}$, but we let $\sqrt{81} = |-9| =  |9| = 9$.

Answer (score 1):

No. $\sqrt a$ conventionally denotes the `non-negative` square root of a non-negative real number, and $x^2\ge 0$ even if $x <0$. Remember a  positive real number has two (opposite) square roots.

Answer (score 1):

The square root $\sqrt{y}$ of a non-negative real number $y$ is, by definition, the unique non-negative real number $x$ such that $x^2=y$. So what does this imply for $\sqrt{x^2}$?

If $x$ is not negative, then obviously the non-negative number whose square is the square of $x$ is $x$ itself.

If $x$ is negative, then $-x>0$, and since $(-x)^2=x^2$, we get $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$.

So to summarize, we have
$$\sqrt{x^2} = \begin{cases}
x & x\ge 0\\
-x & x<0
\end{cases}$$
But that is exactly the definition of $|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the three cases where $x<0$, $x=0$ and $x>0$ separately. In each case, you'll find that $\sqrt{x^2}=\vert x \vert$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the definition of absolute value: If $0\leq a$, then $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the non-negative unique solution of the equation $x^2=a$. Now, since the solutions of the equation $x^2=a^2$ are $x=|a|$ and $a=-|a|$, it follows by the definition that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.